# How does the PATH parameter in windows RegEdit get set when running a web logic service

Tags: java, path, weblogic-10.x, regedit

I have a java app that we deploy as  a windows service.

After I install it I can go to RegEdit and navigate to:
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\beasvc_mydoamain_myserver\parameters

I can see there is a PATH parameter and but the value is empty.

- Where is this value set?

The only place where I can see where something like that is set
C:\bea\wlserver_10.0\common\bin\commEnv.cmd

There is an entry like (and I can see that WL_USE_X86DLL is set to true)

```
@rem add jvm and WebLogic directory in path
if "%WL_USE_X86DLL%" == "true" set PATH=%PATCH_PATH%;%WL_HOME%\server\native\win\32;%WL_HOME%    \server\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%;%WL_HOME%\server\native\win\32\oci920_8
```

I thought that this would set it but it doesn’t.

- Also if the PATH is not set in the registry will it use the system environment’s variables PATH instead?
- What other problems will there be if the path is empty in the registry?

Answer (score 0):

Double click the unset path value to set it. Well that's how it works running Windows through Wine on Mac anyway. I can't really speak to differences from native Windows.

Comment: Hi William, I am actually referring to the script of program that gets run to install the instance as a web logic service. Currently we do set it manually. What I want to do is to change the script that install it to include that PATH. Then is we will always be sure if we need to install/uninstall the service the values will be set again and nothing can be lost when we setup a new server.